# Issuing JSON resquest for openweather in Raspberry Pi Coder

Tags: json, raspberry-pi, openweathermap

I'm learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript with Coder on the Raspberry pi. Currently, I'm trying to make a simple page that displays time, date, and the current weather. Something is going wrong with the `$.getJSON` call in the `getWeather()` function.

Typing the URL passed to `$.getJSON` works correctly (i.e., a page is loaded with all the information in JSON), but the "Got Weather" string is never displayed. I've also tried using the AJAX call requesting JSON or JSONP data type. Neither of those methods worked either. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    //This code will run after your page loads
    function displayTime() {
        var current_time = new Date();
        var hours = current_time.getHours();
        var minutes = current_time.getMinutes();
        var seconds = current_time.getSeconds();
        var meridiem = "AM"; // default is AM

        var day = current_time.getDay();

        if(seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;   
        }

        if(minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;   
        }

        // Set the meridiem for a 12hr clock
        if(hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12; 
            meridiem = "PM"
        } else {
            meridiem = "AM"   
        }
        var clock_div = document.getElementById('clock');
        clock_div.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;

        // Depending on the value of 'day', set the corresponding string
        var day_div = document.getElementById('day');

        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        var today = weekday[current_time.getDay()];
        day_div.innerText = today;

        // Get the date information
        var date = current_time.getDate();
        // Get the year
        var year = current_time.getFullYear();
        // Get the month and set the string
        var month = new Array(12);
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June"; 
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December";

        var this_month = month[current_time.getMonth()];

        // set the string 
        var date_div = document.getElementById('date');
        date_div.innerText = this_month + " " + date + " " + year;
    }

    function getWeather() {
        var api_key = REMOVED; // API key for open weather
        var weather_api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=40.115&lon=-88.27&units=imperial&appid=" + api_key;


        var weather_div = document.getElementById('weather');

        $.getJSON(weather_api).then(function(result){
        //alert("City: "+result.city.name);
        //alert("Weather: "+ result.list[0].weather[0].description);
        weather_div.innerText = "Got Weather";
        });

        //weather_div.innerText = "Got Weather";
    }

    // This runs the displayTime function the first time
    displayTime();
    getWeather();

    // This makes the clock "tick" repeatedly by calling it every 1000 ms 
    setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
    setInterval(getWeather, 2000);

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Coder</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Standard Coder Includes -->
    <script>
        var appname = "{{app_name}}"; //app name (id) of this app
        var appurl = "{{&app_url}}";
        var staticurl = "{{&static_url}}"; //base path to your static files /static/apps/yourapp
    </script>
    <link href="/static/apps/coderlib/css/index.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/static/common/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/common/ace-min/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/apps/coderlib/js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        Coder.addBasicNav();
    </script>
    <!-- extra inludes to get weather from OpenWeather -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End Coder Includes -->

    <!-- This app's includes -->
    <link href="{{&static_url}}/css/index.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{{&static_url}}/js/index.js"></script>
    <!-- End apps includes -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id='day'></div><br>
    <div id='date'></div>
    <div id='clock'></div>
    <div id='weather'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 background-color: black;   
}

#day {
    height:100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; left: 20px;
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
    height:100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px; left: 20px;
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#clock {
    height:100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px; left: 20px;
    font-family: courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Opening up the developer console showed an error along the lines of "Blocked loading mixed active content...". It seems I need to better familiarize myself with the developer tools.

Apps built within Coder are accessed over HTTPS. However, the call to openweather is over HTTP. The openweather API permits HTTPS calls only if you have a pro (paid) subscription. Fortunately, https://forecast.io allows a set number of free calls per day and uses HTTPS.